# How to show $\omega^n$ is a volume form in a symplectic manifold $(M, \omega)$?

Tags: manifolds

I have the following problem: Let $(M, \omega)$ be a symplectic manifold. How can I show $$\omega^n=\underbrace{\omega\wedge \ldots\wedge \omega}_{n-times},$$ satisfies $\omega^n(p)\neq 0$ for all $p\in M$. I believe that is not too dificult but I'm not used with exterior product.. Any help will be valuable...

This is important because the nondegeneracy condition on $ω$ is equivalent to the condition that M has an even dimension $2n$ and the top wedge product $\omega^n$ is nowhere vanishing on M, i.e., $ω^n$ is a volume form. In particular, $M$ must be orientable and is canonically oriented by $\omega^n$.

Comment: I don't know how this is in the context of sympletic manifolds, but as far as I know the wedge product satisfies $\omega \wedge \omega = 0$.

Comment: The nondegeneracy condition on $\omega$ is equivalent to the condition that $M$ has an even dimension $2n$ and the top wedge product $\omega^n$ is nowhere vanishing on $M$,  i.e., $\omega^n$ is a volume form. In particular, $M$ must be orientable and is canonically oriented by $\omega^n$.

Comment: @user1620696:  That equations holds only for odd degree forms.  In general, we have $\alpha \wedge \beta = (-1)^{|\alpha||\beta|}\beta \wedge \alpha$ where $|\alpha|$ denotes the degree of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is really a linear algebra problem - one can work one tangent space at a time.  (In particular, all this works even if $\omega$ isn't closed.)

So, let $\omega$ be a non-degenerate antisymmetric bilinear form on a vector space $V$.  I'd prove $\omega^n\neq 0$ via a sequence of lemmas.

**Lemma 1:**  There is a basis $\{e_i, f_j\}$ for $V$ for which $\omega(e_i,e_j) = \omega(f_i,f_j) = 0$ and $$\omega(e_i,f_j) = \begin{cases} 1 & i = j\\ 0 & i\neq j\end{cases}.$$

This is proved by induction.  At some point, you'll probably use the following fact:  Given any proper subspace $W\subsetneq V$, the subspace $$W^\bot = \{v\in V: \omega(v,w) = 0\text{ for all } w\in W\}$$ has positive dimension -  $\{0\} \subsetneq W^\bot$.  This follows since $W^\bot$ is an intersection of $\dim W$ hyperplanes (codimension 1 planes), corresponding to $\ker(\omega(w_i,\cdot))$ where $\{w_i\}\subseteq W$ is a basis of $W$.

Such basis is called a symplectic basis.  If $\omega$ is allowed to be degenerate, the statement is modified to have a basis of the form $\{e_i, f_j, u_k\}$ where $\omega(u_k,\cdot ) = 0$.

**Lemma 2:**  With respect to a symplectic basis, $\omega$ has the form $\sum_i e_i^\ast\wedge f_i^\ast$

So, proving $\omega^n\neq 0$ for this particular $\omega$ gives the result.

**Lemma 3:** $$\omega^k = k! \sum_{1\leq i_1 < i_2 < \ldots < i_k \leq n } e^\ast_{i_1}\wedge f^\ast_{i_1} \wedge \ldots \wedge e^\ast_{i_k} \wedge f^\ast_{i_k}$$ so, in particular, $\omega^n = n! e^\ast_{1} \wedge f^\ast_{1} \wedge \ldots \wedge e^\ast_n \wedge f^\ast_n$, and hence $\omega^n(e_1,f_1,\ldots e_n,f_n) = n!\neq 0$, so $\omega^n$ is not $0$.

Lemma 3 is proved by induction.

Comment: Let me know if you need further help - I can always fill in more details!

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies a lot =D..

Comment: Jason, perhaps you should fix the typo in the penultimate line, as it's caused some confusion. $\omega^n(e_1,f_1,\dots,e_n,f_n) = n! \ne 0$ :)

Comment: @Ted:  Done.  To whomever I caused confusion - sorry!

Comment: For those wondering why I edited this old post, apparently a typo at the end caused confusion to at least one person (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411971/symplectic-form-and-wedge-sum)

Comment: @JasonDeVito, sir I need help understanding lemma 2 and 3. Can you help me ?

Comment: @Khichudi:  You could ask a separate question on the site, if you want.  In case it helps, $e_i^\ast$ is dual do the basis $\{e_1,..,e_n, f_1,..., f_n\}$ meaning that $e_1^\ast(e_1) = 0$ and $e_1^\ast (x) = 0$ for any other $x$ in the basis.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Forgive me for reviving an older thread, but don't both lemmas 2 & 3 continue to hold - with the proviso that $\omega$ is non-zero - even when $\omega$ is allowed to be degenerate? I may be missing something rather obvious here, but I believe $\omega^n \ne 0$ holds regardless of whether $\omega$ is symplectic or not. As an aside, there is a typo in your previous comment, it should read $e^*_1(e_1) = 1$.

Comment: @MatthewBuck:  I agree my comment has a typo.  Lemma 2 amd 3 are *not* valid for general nonzero forms.  For example, in $\mathbb{R}^4$, the form $\omega= e_1\wedge e_2$ satisfies $\omega^2=0$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thanks for the feedback. I see where my confusion stemmed from: what the integer $n$ is referring to. I stand by my claim that Lemma 2 holds in general, provided we don't insist on $\dim V = 2n$. That is, if $\omega \ne 0$ is an alternating bilinear form on $V$, then there exists a basis ${u_1,\ldots,u_k,e_1,\ldots,e_n,f_1,\ldots,f_n}$ satisfying the properties listed above. Then we have $\omega = \sum_{i=1}^n e_i^* \wedge f_i^*$ and $\omega^n \ne 0$. I appreciate that this is nothing more than applying your result to $\omega$ restricted to the subspace $\mathrm{span}\{e_i,f_i\}$.

Comment: @Matthew:  I should have been more explicit about what $n$ was - sorry about that.