# Double Hodge star without coordinates.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms

The proofs I've found of the fact that $**\alpha=(-1)^{k(n-k)}\alpha$, or, equivalently, the fact that the Hodge star is an isometry, all use an orthonormal basis. Is there a basis-free proof of either of these facts directly from the definition of the Hodge star by

$$\alpha\wedge*\beta=\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle\mathrm{vol}?$$

Comment: I don't agree with the "equivalently." The definition I prefer to use for $\star$ uses an orthonormal basis, so I'm not sure what definition you mean.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think that he is right claiming that the facts are equivalent. Please see my partial answer below.

Comment: @YuriVyatkin, thanks for adding those details; that's exactly the question. I'm not sure which of the two facts ($*$ is an isometry; $**=(-1)^{k(n-k)}$) would be easier to prove without coordinates, but either fact is enough.

Comment: Related question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967980/whats-the-term-for-elements-in-image-of-codifferential-adjoint-exterior-differ @TedShifrin Yasha Berchenko-Kogan

Comment: The statement is obviously incorrect if the metric on the exterior algebra are not induced from the metric on the original vector space. For we can choose two totally unrelated metrics on $k$ forms and $n-k$ forms separately. So I think we need a coordinate independent definition of induced metrics on forms first.

Comment: If $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces with an inner product, then we can define an inner product on $V\otimes W$ in a coordinate-free way as follows. First, define the inner product on simple tensors by $$\langle v_1\otimes w_1,v_2\otimes w_2\rangle:=\langle v_1,v_2\rangle\langle w_1,w_2\rangle,$$ and then extend the definition to all tensors by linearity. We can thus induce a metric on all tensor powers of $V$, and hence we can induce a metric on the exterior algebra as a subspace of the tensor algebra.

Answer (score 8):

Let me make just a partial contribution as an answer, as it is too long for a comment.

Assuming we know that $\star$ is an isometry, and taking the identity in the question as a definition,

$$
\begin{align}
\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle \mathrm{vol} & = \langle \star \alpha, \star \beta \rangle \mathrm{vol} = \star \alpha \wedge \star \star \beta = (- 1)^{k(n-k)}  \star \star \beta \wedge \star \alpha  \\
& = (- 1)^{k(n-k)} \langle \star \star \beta , \alpha \rangle \mathrm{vol} =  (- 1)^{k(n-k)} \langle \alpha , \star \star \beta \rangle \mathrm{vol}
\end{align}
$$

so, we get the desired fact from the non-degeneracy of the metric.

Conversely, if we know, that $**\alpha=(-1)^{k(n-k)}\alpha$ holds, then, considering that

$$
\langle \star \alpha, \star \alpha \rangle \mathrm{vol} = \star \alpha \wedge \star \star \alpha = (-1)^{k(n-k)} \star \alpha \wedge \alpha = \alpha \wedge \star \alpha = \langle \alpha, \alpha \rangle \mathrm{vol}
$$

which implies that $\star$ is an isometry.

Now, we probably want to prove in a coordinate-free manner, that $\star$ is an isometry. However, it looks like a delicate matter, as we can see from the discussion around [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/70938/2002) question, so I feel that I need to take a timeout :)

Comment: Related question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967980/whats-the-term-for-elements-in-image-of-codifferential-adjoint-exterior-differ

Comment: Some insights could be sourced from this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4483178/2002 (I still don't have much time for that, sadly).

Comment: If the determinant of $g_{ij}$ in an orthonormal basis (and hence in each orthonormal basis) is $-1$, then the Hodge operator is not an isometry, is it?

Comment: At least thats what [these notes](https://www2.physik.uni-muenchen.de/lehre/vorlesungen/wise_19_20/Differentiable-Manifolds/material/skript-TMP.pdf) claim, page 32, third line.

Comment: @Filippo You are right in regard that if we wanted to extend this reasoning to the pseudo-Riemannian signature (called Lorentzian in those notes), then we would need to care about the sign. However, the point of my (partial) answer was to find a way to avoid coordinates and frames, and I did not succeed :)

Comment: @YuriVyatkin Thank you very much for having a look and the confirmation :)

Answer (score 4):

As remarked above by Yuri Vyatkin, the Hodge * being an isometry is more or less the same as the double Hodge being $(-1)^{k(n-k)}$ times the identity.

This is my attempt to prove it is an isometry (well,"isometry like": the sign of the innerproduct/nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form is allowed to flip sign) without using a basis. Only for simple (fully decomposable) $k$-vectors however. By (multi)linearity it should work on all of $\Lambda^k(V)$. I guess this is how many properties on $\Lambda(V)$ are defined.

Consider the Grassmann complement. Given a special $n$-covector $\omega$ and also a privileged $n$-vector $\Omega$, the Grassmann complement is a map $*:\Lambda^k(V)\to\Lambda^{n-k}(V^*)$ defined by $$i_{a_1\wedge\dots\wedge a_k}\omega(u_1,\dots,u_{n-k})=\omega(a_1,\dots,a_k,u_1,\dots,u_{n-k}). $$ Similarly $*:\Lambda^k(V^*)\to\Lambda^{n-k}(V)$ - with $\Omega$ instead of $\omega$. (Both directions being called * as well as the Hodge dual denoted * is confusing. Sorry.)
The action of a simple $k$-covector on a simple $k$-vector is given by the determinant
$$ \langle a_1\wedge\dots\wedge a_k,\alpha_1\wedge\dots\wedge \alpha_k\rangle =\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
\langle a_{1},\alpha_{1}\rangle & \cdots & \langle a_{1},\alpha_{k}\rangle\\
\vdots & \ddots\\
\langle a_{k},\alpha_{1}\rangle &  & \langle a_{k},\alpha_{k}\rangle
\end{array}\right|.$$
To find $\langle *(\alpha_{1}\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha_{k}), *(a_{1}\wedge \dots\wedge a_k)\rangle$, we can use that the adjoint of contraction with $\alpha\in V^*$ is wedging with $\alpha$.
$$
\langle *(\alpha_{1}\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha_{k}), *(a_{1}\wedge \dots\wedge a_k)\rangle=\langle i_{\alpha_{1}\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha_{k}}\Omega, i_{a_{1}\wedge \dots\wedge a_k} \omega\rangle\\
=\langle \Omega,\alpha_{1}\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha_{k}\wedge i_{a_{1}\wedge \dots\wedge a_k} \omega\rangle
$$
We also need $i_a (\sigma \wedge \tau)=(i_a \sigma)\wedge \tau + (-1)^{\deg \sigma}\sigma\wedge i_a \tau $ ("$i_a$ is an anti-derivation").
For $k=1$, we simply get
$$
\alpha\wedge i_a\omega = -i_a(\alpha\wedge\omega)+\langle a,\alpha\rangle \omega=\langle a,\alpha\rangle \omega.
$$
Next, $k>1$. By bringing the $i_{a_k}$ to the front in the LHS below, using the anti-derivational character of $i_a$ you get an expansion of the determinant above. (When working with orthonormal/dual bases this step is particularly easy). We get
$$
\alpha_{1}\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha_{k}\wedge i_{a_{k}}\dots i_{a_{1}}\omega=\langle a_1\wedge\dots\wedge a_k,\alpha_1\wedge\dots\wedge \alpha_k\rangle\omega
$$
So
$$
\langle a_1\wedge\dots\wedge a_k,\alpha_1\wedge\dots\wedge \alpha_k\rangle\langle \Omega,\omega\rangle =\langle *(\alpha_{1}\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha_{k}), *(a_{1}\wedge \dots\wedge a_k)\rangle.
$$
In the case of the Hodge * dual we have the volume form $\omega=\sqrt{|g|}dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n$ and also a special $\Omega=\varphi(\omega)$, where $\varphi$ is the Riesz isomorphism (is it called that on Minkowski space too?). We should have $\langle\Omega,\omega\rangle=\sqrt{|g|}\cdot\sqrt{|g|}/\det{g}=\text{sign}(\text{metric})$

(The Clifford answer by Nicholas Todoroff looks pretty neat to me btw. I don't fully understand it.) First post, can't comment.

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand\Ext{{\bigwedge}}
\newcommand\form[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
\newcommand\Cl{\mathrm{Cl}}
\newcommand\rev\widetilde
$We consider the Hodge star on the exterior algebra $\Ext V$ arising from $I \in \mathop{\Ext^{\!n}}V$ and the non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form $\form{\cdot,\cdot}$ on $V$ which extends to $\Ext V$ where $\form{I, I} = \pm1$. We assume $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over a field of characteristic $\not=2$. The bilinear form gives rise to a Clifford algebra $\Cl(V)$ which is canonically isomorphic to $\Ext V$, so we may consider $I$ as an element of $\Cl(V)$ and $\form{\cdot,\cdot}$ as a bilinear form on $\Cl(V)$. It is a fact that
$$
  \form{A, B} = \form{\rev AB}_0,\quad A, B \in \Cl(V)
$$
where $\rev A$ is the *reverse* of $A$ (the main anti-involution which fixes vectors and reverses all products), $\rev AB$ is the Clifford product, and $\form{\cdot}_0$ is the scalar part (i.e. grade 0 projection). It follows from the definition of the Hodge star and well-known properties of the Clifford product that when $A$ and $B$ are $k$-vectors we have
$$
  A\wedge\star B = \form{\rev AB}_0I = \form{A\rev B}_0I = A\wedge(\rev BI).
$$
Since this is true for every $A$, we see
$$
  \star B = \rev BI,
$$
and this equation is true for *all* $B \in \Cl(V) \cong \Ext V$ since it is true for each grade and is linear in $B$.

If $\form{\cdot,\cdot}$ is Euclidean then
$$
  \rev II = \form{\rev II}_0 = \form{I, I} = 1
$$
and also $I^2 = -1$. The fact that the Hodge star is an isometry is now trivial:
$$
  \form{\star A, \star B} = \form{\rev{\rev AI}\rev BI}_0 = \form{\rev IA\rev BI}_0.
$$
At this point, it is well-known that $X \mapsto \rev IXI$ is an orthogonal transformation (this being one of the main features of Clifford algebras; $I$ is an element of the [Pin group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_group), more specifically the [Spin group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group)). We could also argue algebraically to get
$$
  \form{\rev IA\rev BI}_0 = \form{A\rev BI\rev I}_0 = \form{A\rev B}_0 = \form{A, B}.
$$
The double Hodge star formula is also trivial; if $B$ is a $k$-vector
$$
  \star\star B = \rev{\rev BI}I = \rev IBI = (-1)^{n(n-k)}\rev IIB = (-1)^{n(n-k)}B.
$$
I will explain this it bit further. Let e.g. $[B] = \{x \in V \;:\; x\wedge B = 0\}$ be the subspace represented by $B$. $I$ factors as $B^\perp B$ where $[B^\perp] = [B]^\perp$, meaning that $I = B^\perp B = B^\perp\wedge B$. (Clearly, $B^\perp$ is proportional to $\star B$.) The grade of $B$ is $k$ and that of $B^\perp$ is $n-k$ so
$$
  BI = BB^\perp B = (B\wedge B^\perp)B = (-1)^{n(n-k)}(B^\perp\wedge B)B = (-1)^{n(n-k)}IB.
$$
Note that the double Hodge star formula relies on $\form{\cdot,\cdot}$ being Euclidean, and changes for other bilinear forms.