# Hodge decomposition seems to say co-exact component is zero

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, homology-cohomology, differential-forms, hodge-theory

Hodge Decomposition Theorem says smooth  $k$-forms on on compact oriented Riemannian (smooth) $m$−manifold $(M,g)$ (I think M need not be connected, but assume connected if need be or you want) decompose into [exact, co-exact and harmonic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967980/whats-the-term-for-elements-in-image-of-codifferential-adjoint-exterior-differ).

About [this powerpoint](http://math.gmu.edu/%7Ervaughn5/Publications/TheHodgeDecompositionTheorem.pdf),

1. If a smooth $k$-form $\omega = \omega_d \oplus \omega_\delta \oplus \omega_\Delta$ is closed, then is its co-exact component $\omega_\delta$ zero?
2. What exactly is going on in slides 28-41?

   - 2.1. It seems to be proving (1), but actually it appears we have the stronger assumption that $\omega$ is harmonic. In this case, for a smooth $k$-form $\omega$, I think $\omega$ is harmonic if and only if the exact and co-exact components, resp $\omega_d$ and $\omega_\delta$, are both zero. However, I think for a smooth closed $k$-form $\omega$, we have only that $\omega_\delta = 0$ (and $\omega_d]$, all we have is $[\omega_d]=[0]$, but I believe this doesn't even require $\omega$ to be closed).

---

**Update**: Based on [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.4991.pdf), I think: (1) is true, and I think the name for this fact is called 'short Hodge decomposition (theorem)'. As for (2), I think author forgot to explicitly exclude the assumption of harmonic from the claim, which is meant assume closed (instead of harmonic).

Comment: What is $[\omega]$?

Comment: @ArcticChar de rham cohomology class, based on slide 27? (thanks, though it was just a round bracket remark)

Comment: Well, $\omega$ is harmonic if and only if  $\omega_d = \omega_\delta=0$. This is in the statement of Hodge decomposition. I don't know why they try to prove it again...

Comment: @ArcticChar That's why I'm thinking what is being proved is for the case of $\omega$ is closed rather than that $\omega$ is harmonic. notice the other claim is merely that $[\omega_d]=[0]$ instead of that $\omega_d=0$

Comment: @ArcticChar merry christmas, happy new year, and happy holidays!

Comment: @ArcticChar If $\omega$ is closed (but not necessarily harmonic), then is $\omega_{\delta} = 0$?

Comment: @ArcticChar posted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(copying '**Update**' into an answer): Based on [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.4991.pdf), I think: (1) is true, and I think the name for this fact is called 'short Hodge decomposition (theorem)'. As for (2), I think author forgot to explicitly exclude the assumption of harmonic from the claim, which is meant assume closed (instead of harmonic).