# Consequence of Hodge decomposition: What is the norm here?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, homology-cohomology, differential-forms, hodge-theory

Hodge Decomposition Theorem says smooth  $k$-forms on on compact oriented Riemannian (smooth) $m$−manifold $(M,g)$ (I think M need not be connected, but assume connected if need be or you want) decompose into [exact, co-exact and harmonic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967980/whats-the-term-for-elements-in-image-of-codifferential-adjoint-exterior-differ).

About [this pdf powerpoint by Ryan Vaughn](http://math.gmu.edu/%7Ervaughn5/Publications/TheHodgeDecompositionTheorem.pdf),

1. In slides 35-36,40 does $||\alpha||^2$ necessarily refer to the inner product on slide 25 in that $||\alpha||^2 := (\alpha,\alpha):=\int_M \alpha \wedge \star \alpha$, where $\star$ is Hodge star operator?
2. Could it possibly be instead something like $||\alpha||^2 : = g(\alpha,\alpha)$ and then $||\alpha||^2 = 0$ if and only if $(\alpha,\alpha) = 0$?

   - 2.1. Here, I think: we would use that $\alpha \wedge \star \alpha = g(\alpha,\alpha) vol_{(M,g)}$ and then say the integral, of a non-negative integrand, is zero if and only if the integrand is zero.

Comment: Your 1 and 2.1 are the correct interpretation.

Comment: @ArcticChar thanks. are you the downvoter? if not, then is there something wrong with my question?

Comment: @ArcticChar wait, what do you mean? 2.1 is based on (2), not (1)

Comment: @ArcticChar $g(\alpha,\alpha)$ is not necessarily equal to $(\alpha,\alpha)$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't think there is any other reasonable interpretation using the slide besides that
$$ \| \alpha \|^2 = (\alpha, \alpha).$$
This is used in no.34$\to$no.35 and no.39$\to$no.40. And

$$(\alpha, \alpha) = \int_M \alpha \wedge \star \alpha$$

are used when applying the formal adjoint $\delta$ in several places. So 1 is the interpretation used in the slide.

To show that $\|\alpha\| = 0\Rightarrow \alpha = 0$, we use 2.1, that is

$$ \alpha \wedge \star \alpha = g(\alpha,\alpha)\operatorname{ vol}_{(M,g)},$$

so if $\|\alpha\|^2 = 0$, by 1 we have

$$0 = \int_M g(\alpha,\alpha)\operatorname{ vol}_{(M,g)},$$

and since $g(\alpha, \alpha)$ is non-negative, $g(\alpha, \alpha) = 0$ everywhere and thus $\alpha(x) =0$ for all $x\in M$. So $\alpha = 0$.

Comment: i'll just skip the '$\alpha(x) =0$ for all $x\in M$. So' part. lol. thanks Arctic Char! merry christmas, happy new year, and happy holidays!