# Inner product of a quotient space

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, bilinear-form

Let $V$ be an $K$-linear space with inner product, $S \subset V$ a linear subspace and $V/S$ the quotient space. I want to prove that the quadratic form $\psi: V/S \to K$ with $\psi([v])=min\{\|v'\|^2: [v]=[v']\}$ defines an inner product in the quotient.

Should I use the polarization formula $\varphi(v,w)=\frac{1}{4}(\psi(v+w)-\psi(v-w))$ to define the bilinear form, and then use that to prove the properties of the inner product? I'm really lost in that question. Thanks.

Comment: There seems to be a few language problems here. An inner product has $V \times V$ as the domain yet your $\psi$ has $V$ as the domain.  It also doesn't seem that $\psi$ even defines a quadratic form as $\|v'\|$ would typically have a square root involved here.  If it were me, I'd clean up definitions, figure out what inner product this 'sits' on top of and use that to do gram schmidt on $S$ then build to $V/S$

Comment: @user8675309 You're right, I've missed the squared in the definition (actually is $||v'||^2$). I will edit my question. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @user8675309 pointed out in their comment, the question features a mistake of category: after all, an inner product on the vector space $V/S$ is **defined** to be a map
\begin{align}
\varphi:V/S\times V/S&\to\mathbb K\\
(x,y)&\mapsto\varphi(x,y)
\end{align}
with certain properties. In particular it needs *two* arguments, while $\psi$ as defined in the question only takes *one* argument as input. Hence the question is **not** "Is $\psi$ an inner product?" -- because that would mix two *different* types of objects together -- but rather "Can $\psi$ somehow generate an inner product on $V/S$, and if so, how?". And for that second question your idea already goes into the right direction.

In terms of category, $\psi$ is closer to a norm on $V/S$ (one input, non-negative output) so

1. relating $\psi$ to a norm
2. showing that this norm satisfies the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#Normed_vector_spaces_satisfying_the_parallelogram_law)
3. defining an inner product via this norm ([polarization identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/43848)), as is already written in the original question

to me seems like the best course of action.

One readily verifies that given any $v\in V$
$$
\psi([v])=\min_{s\in S}\|v+s\|^2=\min_{s\in S}\langle v+s,v+s\rangle
$$
and thus $\psi(\alpha x)=|\alpha|^2\psi(x)$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb K$, $x\in V/S$. But a norm needs to be homogeneous, that is, $\|\alpha x\|=|\alpha|\|x\|$ which suggests taking the square root of $\psi$. Hence the object of interest becomes
\begin{align}
\sqrt\psi:V/S&\to[0,\infty)\\
x&\mapsto\min_{y\in x}\|y\|\,.
\end{align}
Let us quickly show that $\sqrt\psi$ is indeed a norm: it is homogeneous (by construction), positive definite (if $\sqrt\psi(x)=0$, then $0\in x$ by definiteness of $\|\cdot\|$, so $x=[0]$), and satisfies the triangle inequality: for all $v,w\in V$
\begin{align}
\sqrt\psi([v]+[w])=\sqrt\psi([v+w])&=\min_{s\in S}\|v+w+s\|\\
&\leq \min_{s\in S}\Big(\Big\|v+\frac{s}2\Big\|+\Big\|w+\frac{s}2\Big\|\Big)\\
&\leq \Big(\min_{s\in S}\Big\|v+\frac{s}2\Big\|\Big)+\Big(\min_{s\in S}\Big\|w+\frac{s}2\Big\|\Big)\\
&=\big(\min_{\tilde s\in S}\|v+\tilde s\|\big)+\big(\min_{\tilde s\in S}\|w+\tilde s\|\big)=\sqrt\psi([v])+\sqrt\psi([w])\,.
\end{align}
Now because $\sqrt\psi$ is a norm on $V/S$, all that is left to show is that it satisfies the parallelogram law, i.e. for all $x,y\in V/S$
$$
2\psi(x)+2\psi(y)=\psi(x+y)+\psi(x-y)\tag{1}
$$
Then it would **generate** an inner product on $V/S$ via
\begin{align}
\varphi:V/S\times V/S&\to\mathbb K\\
(x,y)&\mapsto\frac{ (\sqrt\psi(x+y))^2+(\sqrt\psi(x-y))^2 }4=\frac{ \psi(x+y)+\psi(x-y)}4\tag{2}
\end{align}
if $\mathbb K=\mathbb R$ (and analogously if $\mathbb K=\mathbb C$).

In order to show that (1) holds, we have to "explicitly" calculate $\psi([v])$. For this we need the following auxiliary result which is another formulation of the [Hilbert projection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_projection_theorem):

> **Lemma.** Given $v\in V$ and any orthonormal basis $(z_i)_{i=1}^m$ of the orthogonal complement $S^\perp$ of $S$ in $V$, one has
> $$
> \psi([v])=\sum_{i=1}^m|\langle z_i,v\rangle|^2\,.
> $$
> *Proof:* By the projection theorem the minimizer $s_v\in S$ of $\min_{s\in S}\|v-s\|$ is the unique element in $S$ such that $v-s\in S^\perp$. Hence $s_v=\pi_S(v)$ is the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto $S$, and using the Pythagorean theorem we compute
> $$
> \psi([v])=\|v-\pi_S(v)\|^2=\|\pi_{S^\perp}(v)\|^2=\Big\|\sum_{i=1}^m\langle z_i,v\rangle z_i\Big\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^m|\langle z_i,v\rangle|^2\,.\tag*{$\square$}
> $$

With this we can verify (1) by means of a direct computation: given any orthonormal basis $(z_i)_{i=1}^m$ of $S^\perp$ one (in abuse of notation) finds
\begin{align}
\psi([v+w])+\psi([v-w])&=\sum_{i=1}^m|\langle z_i,v\pm w\rangle|^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^m\langle z_i,v\pm w\rangle\langle v\pm w,z_i\rangle\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^m\big(\langle z_i,v\rangle\langle v,z_i\rangle\underbrace{\pm \langle z_i,v\rangle\langle w,z_i\rangle}_{\text{cancel out}}\pm \underbrace{\langle z_i,w\rangle\langle v,z_i\rangle}_{\text{cancel out}}+ \langle z_i,w\rangle\langle w,z_i\rangle\big)\\
&=2\sum_{i=1}^m|\langle z_i,v\rangle|^2+2\sum_{i=1}^m|\langle z_i,w\rangle|^2=2\psi([v])+2\psi([w])\,.
\end{align}
And with this we are done -- as explained above, because $\sqrt\psi$ is a norm which satisfies the parallelogram law it generates an inner product on $V/S$ via (2).

Comment: A good answer... but, as a quibble, the same result holds without assuming that the ground field is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$: it's purely algebraic, I think. Yes, in the Hilbert-space case, the existence and uniqueness of minimizing elements is very useful and clarifying, but, I think, it's not strictly necessary to put it into that context. But I do suspect that the questioner may likely have had that context! :)